# JAVA (jetty), PHP and jQuery Ajax return very big json JSON is not complete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, rest

I'm attempting to retrieve a very big list of Strings back from the server (~4500 String, each String is ~50 chars). my Application is running a Java back-end with REST API, an Apache connecting the client to the server from security manners with PHP code and client side call coming from a jQuery call.

If I put the URL in the browser is the the full output of the JSON, but when I call it from the script it only receive an array of 42 items.

I Check JSON is formatted well when return, and couldnt find anything that limit the respons size.

What can be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: There may be something wrong with your PHP security layer, as far as i understand. Can you provide some code?

Comment: @MehmetSeçkin added - everything is ok in the php as I do see the respons in a fresh browser when entering the url of the call

Comment: Hmm, everything seems okay, I think the problem is inside the `getProtectionsList(packNumberDec)` method, in the Java part. Maybe it stops reading when it encounters an empty string?